# What is the chance of this dice appearing twice in a row?

Tags: probability, dice

3 friends roll a 6-sided dice. What is the probability that at least two of them roll the same number?

Comment: What do you mean "any"? The "same number" as who? Do you mean that at least two of the friends roll the same number or something else?

Comment: At least 2 of the friends roll same number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_{i}$ be the number that friend $i$ rolls for $i=1,2,3$.  Furthermore, let $A_{1}=\{X_{1}=X_{2}\}$, $A_{2}=\{X_{2}=X_{3}\},$ and $A_{3}=\{X_{1}=X_{3}\}$.  Then we seek the probability $P(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3})$.  This is computed using the inclusion-exclusion principle as follows $$P(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3})=\\ \sum_{i=1}^{3}P(A_{i})-P(A_{1} \cap A_{2})-P(A_{2} \cap A_{3})-P(A_{1} \cap A_{3})+P(A_1 \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}).$$
Now, observe that the rolls of the three friends are independent, and that each of $P(A_{i} \cap A_{j})=P(A_{i}\,|\,A_{j})P(A_{j})$ for $1\leq i, j \leq3$ such that $i \neq j$, and $P(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3})=P(A_{1}\,|\,A_{2} \cap A_{3})P(A_{2} \cap A_{3})=P(A_{1}\,|\,A_{2} \cap A_{3})P(A_{3}\,|\,A_{2})P(A_{2}).$ This should give you enough ammunition to finish the problem.  Note that, for example, $$P(A_{1})=P(X_1=X_2=x)=P(X_1=x,X_2=x)=P(X_1=x)P(X_2=x)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2=\frac{1}{36}$$
for $x \in \{1,...,6\}$, where the third equality is by the independence of the rolls of the dice.  **Key hint**: as an instance of conditional events in this context, suppose that the second friend rolls the same number as the third friend.  Will this assumption affect the chances that the first friend rolls the same number as the third friend?

Comment: In the last displayed equation you are defining $A_1$ differently than you did in the opening paragraph ($\{X_1=X_2=x\}$ vs. $\{X_1=X_2\}$).  With the original definition, $P(A_1)$ should be $1/6.$  Also, this problem becomes easier if you start by computing the probability of the complementary event.

Comment: This is a complete solution from the basics of probability without using elementary tricks...I understand there are easier methods if you know what you're doing, trust me @WillOrrick...also, this is the same thing, I was only illustrating $X_1 = X_2$ with some concrete value in the random variables' domains...the "vs" probabilities you mentioned are equivalent

Comment: How should it be $\frac{1}{6}$? $$P(X_1=X_2) = P(X_1 = X_2 = x) = P(X_1 = x, X_2 = x) = P(X_1 = x)P(X_2 = x) = \frac{1}{36}$$ for some $x$ in the domain of $X_1,X_2$...@WillOrrick

Comment: $P(X_1=X_2)=1/6$ since $X_2$ can take $6$ different values, one of which is the same as $X_1.$  Another way to see it: let $(a,b)$ denote the outcome where $X_1=a$ and $X_2=b.$  Then the event $X_1=X_2$ is $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)\}.$  The sample space has $6^2=36$ outcomes, each with probability $1/36.$  So the event $X_1=X_2$ has probability $6/36=1/6.$

Comment: Also, $P(X_1=X_2)=1/6$ gives the right answer when used in your inclusion-exclusion formula.  Due to transitivity of equality, $A_1\cap A_2,$ $A_1\cap A_3,$ $A_2\cap A_3,$ and $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3$ are all the same event, namely $X_1=X_2=X_3,$ which has probability $1/36.$  Putting everything together, one gets the same answer as one gets using the complement method: $$P(\text{at least two of $X_1,\ X_2,\ X_3$ equal})=1-P(X_1,\ X_2,\ X_3\text{ all different})=1-\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{6\cdot6\cdot6}.$$  This problem is, of course, a variant of the birthday problem.

Comment: Good looks @WillOrrick

Comment: @WillOrrick btw there is a lot less motivation to use the complement here than there is in the birthday problem, but okay...this is actually a good example to show inclusion-exclusion and probability principles