# Rolling a dice n times - probability that only k sides show up.

Tags: probability, statistics

I roll a dice $3$ times. What is the probability that only $2$ of the sides show up, or put equivalently, what is the probability that 4 of the sides don't show up at all?

More generally lets say I have a $20$ numbered balls in a bag. I pull one out, write down its number and put it back, I then pull another out. I repeat this procedure $8$ times. What is the probability that exactly $14$ of the balls don't show up at all?

Thanks.

Comment: In the die problem, are you asking for the probability that exactly two of the sides show up, or for the probability that no more than two of the sides show up?

Comment: No more than 2 show up.

Comment: **Hint**: Look at my answer to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790014/what-is-the-chance-of-this-dice-appearing-twice-in-a-row/790125#790125

Comment: The second question is not a generalization of the first one since in the first question you ask for "not more than 2" and in the second question you ask for "exactly 6".

Comment: One last time before I give up. I have a bag with 20 numbered balls. I am interested to know that in 8 tries the probability that 6 balls show up more than once.

Comment: I've posted an answer to the balls question.  I hope I had the right interpretation!  The die question is different from the balls question.  In the die question you could have only one side show up (and five not show up) or two sides show up (and four not show up), whereas in the balls question you must have six balls showing up one or more times and 14 balls not showing up.  (I assume that you meant "one or more times" rather than "more than once", since to have six balls each show up more than once you'd have to have at least 12 draws.

Answer (score 2):

If $8$ balls are drawn in order, then an example of an outcome in which exactly $6$ different balls appear is
$$
8,\ 6,\ 8,\ 9,\ 19,\ 3,\ 6,\ 2.
$$
In this example, ball $8$ came up on draws $1$ and $3,$ ball $6$ came up on draws $2$ and $7,$ and balls $9,$ $19,$ $3,$ and $2$ came up on draws $4,$ $5,$ $6,$ and $8,$ respectively.  This shape of this outcome can be described as a particular partition of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\},$ namely $\{\{1,3\},\{2,7\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\},\{8\}\}.$  The outcome itself corresponds to the association of the six numbers $8$, $6,$ $9,$ $19,$ $3,$ and $2$ with the elements of this partition.

These observations suggest the following procedure for enumerating the desired outcomes:

1. choose $6$ numbers from the $20$ in the bag;
2. partition the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ into $6$ nonempty unlabeled subsets;
3. label these $6$ subsets using the $6$ numbers chosen from the bag.

There are $\binom{20}{6}\cdot\left\{8\atop6\right\}\cdot6!$ ways to accomplish these steps, where $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  To make this a probability, divide by $20^8.$

Comment: Many thanks, Will. Looks like you know best.

Comment: Now, can I apply the formula above to calculate the probability that 1) all eight draws are different; 2) eight draws produce 7 distinct balls, and so on...?

Comment: Can I directly contact you at: worrick@indiana.edu?

Comment: Sure!  I'd be happy to discuss this further.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of $2$ of them showing up in one is $\frac13$. Because you roll it $3$ times you get $\left(\frac13\right)^3=\frac1{27}$. For the ball one the probability of not getting $14$ on one turn is $\frac6{20}=\frac3{10}$.
$\left(\frac3{10}\right)^8=\frac{6561}{100000000}=6.561\cdot 10^{-5}$ which is a very small probability.